# In a ROOTLESS podman setup, how to communicate between containers in different pods

Tags: containers, podman, redhat-containers, podman-compose

I read all I could find, but documentation on this scenario is scant or unclear for `podman`. I have the following (contrived) `ROOTLESS` `podman` setup:

- pod-1 name: `pod1`

  Container names in `pod1`:

  - `p1c1`  -- This is also it's assigned `hostname` within `pod1`
  - `p1c2`  -- This is also it's assigned `hostname` within `pod1`
  - `p1c3`  -- This is also it's assigned `hostname` within `pod1`
- pod-2 name: `pod2`

  Container names in `pod2`:

  - `p2c1`  -- This is also it's assigned `hostname` within `pod2`
  - `p2c2`  -- This is also it's assigned `hostname` within `pod2`
  - `p2c3`  -- This is also it's assigned `hostname` within `pod2`

I keep certain containers in different `pods` specifically to avoid `port conflict`, and to manage containers as groups.

**QUESTION**:

Give the above topology, how do I communicate between, say, `p1c1` and `p2c1`? In other words, step-by-step, what `podman(1)` commands do I issue to collect the necessary `addressing information` for `pod1:p1c1` and `pod2:p2c1`, and then use that information to configure applications in them so they can communicate with one another?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**: For searchers, additional information can be found [here](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/master/docs/tutorials/basic_networking.md).

Comment: The same question can be found here: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/10054

Comment: Indeed. I cross-posted this question on `GitHub`, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Podman doesn't have anything like the "services" concept in Swarm or Kubernetes to provide for service discovery between pods. Your options boil down to:

1. Run both pods in the same network namespace, or
2. Expose the services by publishing them on host ports, and then access them via the host

For the first solution, we'd start by creating a network:

```
podman network create shared
```

And then creating both pods attached to the `shared` network:

```
podman pod create --name pod1 --network shared
podman pod create --name pod2 --network shared
```

With both pods running on the same network, containers can refer to
the other pod by name.  E.g, if you were running a web service in
`p1c1` on port 80, in `p2c1` you could `curl http://pod1`.

For the second option, you would do something like:

```
podman pod create --name pod1 -p 1234:1234 ...
podman pod create --name pod2 ...
```

Now if `p1c1` has a service listening on port `1234`, you can access that from `p2c1` at `<some_host_address>:1234`.

---

> If I'm interpreting option 1 correctly, if the applications in p1c1 and p2c1 both use, say, port 8080; then there won't be any conflict anywhere (either within the pods and the outer host) IF I publish using something like this: 8080:8080 for app in p1c1 and 8081:8080 for app in p2c1? Is this interpretation correct?

That's correct. Each pod runs with its own network namespace
(effectively, it's own ip address), so services in different pods can
listen on the same port.

> Can the network (not ports) of a pod be reassigned once running? REASON: I'm using podman-compose(1), which creates things for you in a pod, but I may need to change things (like the network assignment) after the fact. Can this be done?

In general you cannot change the configuration of a pod or a
container; you can only delete it and create a new one. Assuming that
`podman-compose` has relatively complete support for the
`docker-compose.yaml` format, you should be able to set up the network
correctly in your `docker-compose.yaml` file (you would create the
network manually, and then reference it as an `external` network in
your compose file).

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network) is a link to the relevant Docker documentation. I haven't tried this myself with podman.

Comment: If I'm interpreting option `1` correctly, if the applications in `p1c1` and `p2c1` both use, say, port `8080`; then there won't be any conflict anywhere (either within the `pods` and the outer `host`) **IF** I `publish` using something like this: `8080:8080` for app in `p1c1` and `8081:8080` for app in `p2c1`? Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: This is a separate question to the above comment question (so I have two follow-ups now). Can the `network` (not `ports`) of a `pod` be reassigned once running? REASON: I'm using `podman-compose(1)`, which creates things for you in a `pod`, but I may need to change things (like the `network assignment`) after the fact. Can this be done?

Comment: I've updated the question with answers to your comments.

Comment: Indeed, I'm hoping that `podman-compose` supports external networks too, because that's what I do with `docker-compose`. Thank you for the follow-ups. This Q&A session will be useful to others I think.

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer from @larsks will only work for rootful containers. In other words, run every podman commands with `sudo` prefix. (For instance when you connect postgres container from spring boot application container, you will get SocketTimeout exception)

If two containers will work on the same host, then get the ip address of the host, then `<ipOfHost>:<port>`. Example: `192.168.1.22:5432`

For more information you can read this blog => https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/container-networking-podman

Answer (score -2):

Note: The above solution of creating networks, only works in rootful mode.  You cannot do podman network create as a rootless user.

Comment: That's incorrect. I run `jdoe$ podman network create mynetwork` as a `non-root` user (i.e. as myself) all the time. In fact, I never use `rootful` podman. To avoid being `down-voted`, I recommend correcting this. Also, this should be a comment not an answer, because it doesn't answer the question (it's a side comment).

Comment: I literally get an error that says, "network create is not supported in rootless mode"

Comment: You probably have an old version of `podman(1)` or have not configured your `podman(1)` environment correctly. Upgrade `podman(1)` to the latest, then search for combinations of `rootless ` and `~/.config/containers/storage.conf`, `~/.config/containers/containers.conf` and `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` for examples.

Comment: I'm stuck using version 1.6.4 on CentOS 7 version 1160. I work for a government contractor and I don't have the luxury of upgrading because that's the version that has been approved for us to use. It would be months before I'm allowed to upgrade to even version 1.9

Comment: Bummer. But your answer is still incorrect and you should remove it.