# How to Communicate Between Pods on a Rootless Network

Tags: podman

I'm trying to create a set of pods intercommunicating with one another over REST, but can't seem to get DNS resolution established between pods. I've looked at [Rootless Pod Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67126730/in-a-rootless-podman-setup-how-to-communicate-between-containers-in-different-p) but the provided answer does not appear to work...

[Communicate different Pods using Podman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71141056/communicate-different-pods-using-podman) has a similar solution, with a caveat that the provided `podman run` commands don't even execute/return correctly. It also has a comment with negative upvotes indicating that the solution is to use the [dnsname plugin](https://github.com/containers/dnsname). I looked into the plugin, and it hasn't been updated in ~8 months. Furthermore, [this issue](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/8040#issuecomment-709948615) seems to indicate that the plugin is unnecessary when operating rootless (due to the infra containers).

The following is the code I've used to create my network/pods. I've also tried using `network=test-network` with the run commands, but when I do that the pods end up in a degraded state (presumably because the infra containers end up in a configured state but not a running state).

```
podman network create test-network

podman pod create --name test-pod1 --network test-network --share net
podman run \
    --pod=test-pod1 -d \
    --name=test-container1 \
    --network-alias=test-pod1-alias \
    --add-host test-container1:127.0.0.1 \
    --entrypoint='["/bin/sh","-c", "while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done"]' \
    ubi/ubi8:latest test-container1

podman pod create --name test-pod2 --network test-network --share net
podman run \
    --pod=test-pod2 -d \
    --name=test-container2 \
    --network-alias=test-pod2-alias \
    --add-host test-container2:127.0.0.1 \
    --entrypoint='["/bin/sh","-c", "while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done"]' \
    ubi/ubi8:latest test-container2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appear to have had some success fixing the problem by installing `podman-plugins` from `rhel8-appstream` using `dnf install podman-plugins`.

It seems that the dnsname plugin is not included in container-tools or in containernetworking-plugins, and is required for the DNS to actually work. Once I installed the podman-plugins I've succeeded in executing ping calls from test-container1 to test-pod2. However, I still don't have any DNS between test-container1 and test-container2 or test-container2-alias.